# how to get EventHub Namespace SAS keys from powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, connection-string, azure-powershell, azure-eventhub

Previously Powershell module `AzureRm.EventHub` had `Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespaceKey` and it was easy to get the keys. now it is removed since powershell v5 . Now how can i get the EventHubNameSpace SAS Key. here's the list of powershell Get cmdlets i found in my machine.

```
Get-AzureRmEventHub
Get-AzureRmEventHubAuthorizationRule
Get-AzureRmEventHubConsumerGroup
Get-AzureRmEventHubGeoDRConfiguration
Get-AzureRmEventHubKey
Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespace
Get-AzureRmIotHubEventHubConsumerGroup
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` to do that:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName rgName -ResourceType Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/AuthorizationRules -ResourceName eventhubName/RootManageSharedAccessKey -Action listKeys -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks alot!